# Mass editing (find and replace) docx files and its footer and header with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, footer, docx

I am trying to create a script using Powershell to mass edit docx files in a folder. I am trying to have them replace a string "154" to "12" in this case. It works, except it won't edit the footer of the document. How can I modify my code so it would do that too?

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

# Search for all Word document types (.doc, .docx, .doct, etc.)
$WordFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? Name -like "*.do[c,t]*"

$FindText = "154" # <= Find this text
$ReplaceText = "12" # <= Replace it with this text

$MatchCase = $false
$MatchWholeWorld = $true
$MatchWildcards = $false
$MatchSoundsLike = $false
$MatchAllWordForms = $false
$Forward = $false
$Wrap = 1
$Format = $false
$Replace = 2

foreach($WordFile in $WordFiles) {
    # Open the document
    $Document = $Word.Documents.Open($WordFile.FullName)
    
    # Find and replace the text using the variables we just setup
    $Document.Content.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWorld, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, $ReplaceText, $Replace)
    
    # Save and close the document
    $Document.Close(-1) # The -1 corresponds to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveoptions
}
```

Comment: I think you'll want to loop over `$Document.StoryRanges` (which should contain both the content range and footer range) and then apply the Find/Replace operation on each of those

Answer (score 0):

Mathias is correct in their comment. Iterating over `$Document.StoryRanges` and using the `Find.Execute` operation on each `StoryRange` will edit the header/footer as well as the text in document.

```
foreach($WordFile in $WordFiles) {
    # Open the document
    $Document = $Word.Documents.Open($WordFile.FullName)
    # Find and replace the text using the variables we just setup
    foreach ($story in $Document.StoryRanges){
        $story.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWorld, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, $ReplaceText, $Replace)
    }
    # Save and close the document
    $Document.Close(-1) # The -1 corresponds to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveoptions
}
```